# What are the wires of headphones made up of?

Tags: headphones, wire-size

Of what material are headphone wires made up of? Are they made up of copper? Can can replace the wires in it with copper wire?

Comment: Headphone wire is copper or aluminum, either with plastic isolation or enamel. If you want to extend headphone wire by soldering to the existing wire, be reminded of the fact that you can’t solder aluminum. If you have enameled wire you should first remove the enamel from the wire where you want to solder it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be made of stranded copper wire. You may want to choose wires with a higher strand count (more, finer strands) if you want your cable to be more flexible.

Comment: They are often made from helically-wound copper tape, which is more flexible than round wire and resistant to fatigue, and glass fibre reinforcement down the middle of the helix makes the cable very strong in tension.  Thee we copper is often lacquered to minimise corrosion, but that makes it difficult to solder.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes tinsel wire.
sometimes insulated copper wire.
sometimes magnet wire.

And yes, ordinary insulated copper wire will work fine in this application